# Groovy xml processing syntax

Tags: xml, groovy, rest-assured

I have an XML like this:

```
<countries>
    <country>
           <country_id>10</country_id>
           <providers>
             <provider>
                <id>1</id>
                <name>Name</name>
             </provider>
             <provider>
                <id>2</id>
                <name>Name2</name>
             </provider>
       ...
   </country>
</countries>
```

This is the response of a service I'm calling and testing with rest-assured. Based on a provider ID, I need to extract the country id. In the case above, for the id=1 I need country_code = 10. (It's the same for id=2, country_code=10).

I saw that rest-assured uses groovy syntax to traverse the xml document, but as I have no experience with groovy I'm stuck.

I was trying something like this (with a hardcoded ID):

```
path.getList("countries.country.findAll{country -> country.providers.provider.id == '1' }.country_id", Integer.class);
```

to return the id of countries a provider with id 1 is active in, but this does not work.

Can you please give me some hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If more than one country can match, it'd be safer to do something like:

```
countries.country.findAll { country -> 
  country.providers.provider.any{ it.id == '1' }
}*.country_id
```

Otherwise, it could simply be:

```
countries.country.find { it.providers.provider.any{ it.id == '1' }}.country_id
```